# Can you temporarily disable/override Control Template Triggers in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, triggers

I'm setting the **BorderBrush** of a **TextBox** if I input invalid Text in it:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtAddName.Text, @"[^A-Za-z0-9|()& ]"))
{
    txtAddName.BorderBrush = regularBrush;
}
else
{
    txtAddName.BorderBrush = errorBrush;
}
```

However the **BorderBrush** I set gets overwritten by the **Control Template Triggers**:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#505F69"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#505F69"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

So I need to disable them somehow, until I lose focus of the **TextBox** or the text is valid. I thought about making a **Multitrigger** out of it and set a second condition, but I cant imagine how this condition should look like. Is there a simple way to do that? Couldn't find anything useful yet.

Is there something like this possible:

In Code setting a **bool**:

```
bool isTextInvalid;
if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtAddName.Text, @"[^A-Za-z0-9|()& ]"))
{
    txtAddName.BorderBrush = regularBrush;
    isTextInvalid = false;
}
else
{
    txtAddName.BorderBrush = errorBrush;
    isTextInvalid = true;
}
```

and then in XAML accessing this **bool** ?

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="isTextInvalid" Value="False"/>   <-- The bool from code
                <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#505F69"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: To let the trigger notice the value changes, change notifications must be published/raised. I.e. `isTextInvalid` should be implemented as a **DependencyProperty** (since it seems a property of the Control itself and not of the ViewModel/DataContext).

Comment: In case the code you've shown belongs to the viewmodel then  `isTextInvalid` should be declared as a **public property** and you'd need to raise `PropertyChanged` in the setter.
If is a vm then the triggers for `isTextInvalid` need to be a DataTrigger (I don't know by heart how you can combine Trigger+DataTrigger).

Comment: If I were you, I'd remove the code-behind with the Regex, and instead move all of that code to a ValueConverter.  Then, in your xaml, add a 3rd trigger that feeds off of that value converter: `<DataTrigger Property="{Binding ElementName=txtAddName,Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource MyRegexErrorConverter}" Value="True"> ...`  Note that the xaml triggers are in order-of-operation, therefore if you make this the 3rd trigger, it will override the other two if it's true. I could show this in an answer response if this comment is not clear.

Comment: Why don't you use standard validation? If that really doesn't suit then an adorner like the standard validation template.

Comment: @TamBui I got it working with the Tag solution by mm8, but I definitely like to see how I could add that ValueConverter to XAML, if you dont mind showing an example? I'm still relatively new to binding stuff in xaml. thanks a lot

Comment: Sure, I'll write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Tag` property to store the current value of `isTextInvalid`:

```
txtAddName.BorderBrush = regularBrush;
txtAddName.Tag = false;
```

**XAML:**

```
<MultiTrigger xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="Tag">
            <Condition.Value>
                <sys:Boolean>false</sys:Boolean>
            </Condition.Value>
        </Condition>
        <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#505F69"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
</MultiTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your TextBox's Text validity takes precedence over the other triggers, you could do this all with a `ValueConverter`, a `Style` with triggers (no ControlTemplate triggers), and no code-behind.

Here's a working example:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyRegexValueConverter x:Key="MyRegexConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtAddName" Width="300" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="2" Padding="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#505F69"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#505F69"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource MyRegexConverter}}" Value="True"
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF0000"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

MyRegexValueConverter.cs:

```
public class MyRegexValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var textValue = System.Convert.ToString(value);

        // Returns true if text is invalid, otherwise false
        return Regex.IsMatch(textValue, @"[^A-Za-z0-9|()& ]");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Example output with IsMouseOver or IsFocused:

[image]

Example output with invalid Text:

[image]

I tested this in a new WPF project and it works. Hope you find it useful.